# Is spotipy's current_user_top_artists only working for premium users?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to get the top artists of several accounts. While this code works and prints my artists, it only prints an empty list with the account of a friend.

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, redirect_uri='http://localhost')

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    print(sp.current_user_top_tracks(20, 0, "medium_term"))

    artists = (sp.current_user_top_artists(limit=500, offset=0, time_range='medium_term'))['items']
    print(artists)
```

I suspect it might have something to do with the fact that I had premium for a while, while she hasn't. We both use our account since over a year.